# Override Strategy for Hibernate For Unit Tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

We have a parent entity class that defines a strategy for generating id's using a class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "oid", strategy = "com.ourcompany.ourproject.jpa.util.OurIDGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "oid")
    protected BigInteger id;
```

I am trying to use H2 for my JUnit tests which partially supports BitInteger (it actually supports long)

What I want to do is change the strategy only within my unit test to generate values that will fit for longs.  I've tried mocking OurIDGenerator as well as the hibernate method returning the OurIDGenerator class with no luck.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should choose Long over BigInteger because it's better candidate to be @Id representation. What's more testing with Long type and running app with BigInteger can produce diffrent result. Beside that database for tests and app also should be same.